# Installing Hyper-V server on same partition as OS (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, virtualization, hyper-v

I need to do multiple `Internet Explorer` version testing and [one of suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the#answer-574465) is [to install Modern.IE](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/). To do this one needs visualization running. I have downloaded [Remote Server Administration Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) and [Hyper-V server 2012 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2?i=1). When installing `Hyper-V` it asked me which partition do I want to use. It does not allow me to split my disk on the fly and only partition I have is one that my OS (`Windows 7`) is running on.

[image]

[Architecture-wise partition is used as separate unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Architecture), which makes me wonder.

**Is it safe to install `Hyper-V server 2012 R2` on same partition as my OS or should I split the drive before going any further?**

Comment: You do understand that `Hyper-V server 2012 R2` is an OS right?  You can use VirtualBox, VMWare, VirtualPC all work on Windows 7 and all are supported formats that Microsoft has pre-configured virtual machines for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not install Hyper-V onto the same partition as your Windows 7. You want to use a separate partition for every Windows installation.

I'm not even sure the installation routine would let you do that (in the next steps)

Do you have a second machine to manage the Hyper-V Server with and RDP into the VMs?

Otherwise it may make more sense to upgrade to Windows 8.1 (or 10) Pro and use the Hyper-V that comes with these OSes.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for your answer. No I don't have second machine and not very well versed in visualization. Are you saying that running Hyper-V Server 2012 from Win7 might be an issue?

Comment: Hyper-V Server is a different OS which you run dual-boot with your Windows 7. So either Hyper-V Server or Windows 7, never both. Hyper-V server has a very limited GUI, no Windows Explorer, no Internet Explorer. It just runs VMs. It also has limited graphics drivers, so if you know what you doing on the command line to set up VMs you can do that, but you can't really do your IE testing on the same machine. You may want to look into running those modern.ie VMs in a different solution like VirtualBox, that would run within your existing Windows 7